# If a particular field output value will negative so that how can i set it to 0 when view the XML file in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to calculate the difference value between the two fields in ORM. If the result value is negative it will the value 0 when I show this field value using XML.

```py
excess_amount = fields.Float(string="Excess amount", compute='difference_excess_amount')
  
def difference_excess_amount(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.excess_amount = rec.actual_total - rec.expected_total
```

```xml
<field name="excess_amount"/>
```

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
@api.depends('actual_total', 'expected_total')
def difference_excess_amount(self):
    for rec in self:
        excess_amount = rec.actual_total - rec.expected_total
        rec.excess_amount = 0 if excess_amount < 0 else excess_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@api.depends('actual_total', 'expected_total')
def difference_excess_amount(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.excess_amount = rec.actual_total - rec.expected_total
        if rec.excess_amount < 0:
            rec.excess_amount = 0
```

This should work.

Comment: This code does not work for a negative value. It converts all types of values to 0.

Comment: sorry. I get stupid sometimes of day :))))